# How do I update 16.04 xubuntu to use xfce4-power-manager v1.6?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, power-management

xubuntu 16.04 uses xfce4-power-manager v 1.4.2
The current upstream stable is 1.6. It has improvements relating to see what is inhibiting power management, which I'm curious about.

Can anyway give me guidance about how I would install it?

Comment: The debian people mark version 1.6 as 'experimental' (see https://packages.debian.org/experimental/xfce4-power-manager). So it probably will not be in official (stable) ubuntu releases.

Comment: Even in Ubuntu zesty power-manager is still version 1.4.4-4 (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/zesty/xfce4-power-manager). The only way to install would be to get the debian package and install (at your own risk; dependencies might not be fulfilled).